# Polling for REST API value in Java

Tags: java, testng

An external application needs a few seconds to finish a job. It keeps exposing "RUNNING" state and then it exposes "FINISHED". I'm developing a test that needs to block until "FINISHED" state appear. the test fails when the timeout is reached.

{
state: "RUNNING"
}

The way I'm handling this today is the following:

```
@Test(timeout = 20000)
public void myTest() {
  String state = null;
  while(!"FINISHED".equals(state) {
    state = callAPIandGetStateAsString();
    try {
      TimeUnit.SECOND.sleep(3);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      fail("Message" + e);
    }
    assertEquals(state, "FINISHED");
  }
```

My question is: Is there a better way to poll for an external value to change without using `Timeout.SECOND.sleep()` method? If it was a multithreading situation I would have used a `CountDownLatch` but I'm wondering how should I handle this situation in the case of an external REST API

Comment: You could use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-delay-code-execution#service), with your task somehow reregistering itself against the executor if it didn't receive `"FINISHED"`.

Comment: You could use [tempus-fugit's `waitOrTimeout(...)` method](http://tempusfugitlibrary.org/documentation/junit/waiting/) for probing on given values or throw an exception on timeouts

Comment: You can use Resilience4J's [retry](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/retry). If the timeout actually matters you can combine it with [time limiter](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/timeout).

Comment: Try [polling](https://github.com/fslev/jtest-utils#polling) support from [jtest-utils](https://github.com/fslev/jtest-utils). You could even try using one of the object matchers which which already has embedded polling.